# What happens to repositories when the template repository is deleted?

Tags: github

If I am using a private GitHub repository fork as a template, and I create a second private repository using the first as a template, what happens if I lose access to the original repo (or if it is deleted)?

Will this not have any effect, or will the repository created with the template be deleted?

Comment: it should keep the one that was created from the template. a template is a starting point